# How to disable Race Cache With Network (RCWN) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cache

I just learned that Firefox has a cache racing feature, where if the disk cache is slow, it will fetch the data from server. However what Firefox developers did not consider is that some people may be on an expensive data plan. I have my desktop connected via USB tethering and all those raced requests cost me money.

So I wanted to ask, how to disable this feature while I am on data plan and pay per byte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox sends requests for cached resources concurrently to the local disk cache and the actual network server. Whichever result arrives first is used, the other request is canceled.
The idea is that sometimes the network is faster that the cache on HDD, so this way the page is loaded faster.

To turn it off, open `about:config` and set `network.http.rcwn.enabled` to  *false*.

If you enter in `about:config` only the text `rcwn`, you will find more parameters
for finer control of this feature, such as
`network.http.rcwn.cache_queue_normal_threshold`.
However, I haven't found any documentation for these parameters.